# Dropdown populate table ajax codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to make an application in ajax in codeigniter, to choose a type of product and appears a table that contains the marks the price of the product

So here is what I have done and thank you for helping me with this code.
Controller:

```html
public function produit()
 {
  $data['listType']=$this->test_m->findtype();
  return $this->load->view('produit',$data);//List of product types 
 }
  
 public function getprod($idv)
 {
  $this->test_m->idv=$idv;
  $prod=$this->test_m->req_prod();
  header('Content-Type: application/x-json;      charset=utf-8');//to display the table 
       echo json_encode($prod);
 }
```

Model:

```html
function findtype()
    {
     $query=$this->db->get('valve'); 
     return $query->result(); //dropdown types
    }

    function req_prod()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->idv)){
            $this->db->select('taille,reference,marque,prix,quantite ');
            $this->db->where('idv', $this->idv);
            $prod = $this->db->get('produit');

            // if there are suboptinos for this option...
            if($prod->num_rows() > 0){
                $prod_arr;

                // Format for passing into jQuery loop

                foreach ($prod->result() as $option) {
                    $prod_arr[] = $option->taille;
                    $prod_arr[] = $option->reference;
                    $prod_arr[] = $option->marque;
                    $prod_arr[] = $option->prix;
                    $prod_arr[] = $option->quantite;

                }

                return $prod_arr;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

And view:

```html
<div id="ess">
 <select name="vl1" id="vl1">
  <option>--select valve--</option>
  <?php foreach($listType as $pr){?>
  <option value="<?php echo $pr->idv;?>"><?php echo $pr->type?></option>
  <?php }?>
 </select><br>
</div>
<p>Nos produits</p>
<div id="pr1">
 <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="prod">
                    <td><label>Produits au choix</label></td>
                         
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#vl1').change(function(){ //any select change on the dropdown with id options trigger this code
            var idvlv = $('#vl1').val();  // here we are taking option id of the selected one.

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/test_c/getprod/"+idvlv , //here we are calling our dropdown controller and getprod method passing the option
 
                success: function(prod) //we're calling the response json array 'suboptions'
                {
                    $.each(prod,function(taille,reference,marque,prix,quantite) //here we're doing a foeach loop round each sub option with id as the key and value as the value
                    {
                        var opt = $('<td/>'); // here we're creating a new select option for each suboption
                        opt.val(taille);
                        opt.val(reference);
                        opt.val(marque);
                        opt.val(prix);
                        opt.val(quantite);
                        $('#prod').append(opt); //here we will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'suboptions'
                    });
                }
 
            });
 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The error is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
And: [Violation] Long running JavaScript task took 304ms

Answer (score 0):

Before ajax add this.

```
var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
```

In routes add,

$['test'] = 'controller/function';

and in ajax request,

```
url: BASE_URL + 'test';
data:{data:idvlv},
```

and in controller,

$this->input->post('data');

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried but even error

Comment: May be that the controller that there are faults,but i don't know